# Java and Access - use Prepared Statement and get date

Tags: java, date, ms-access, ucanaccess

I'm doing a JavaAFX application using the MS Access 2007 database. I need to extract data from the database by filtering after the date.

This work good:

```
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Notification WHERE 
postDate>=#2018-01-18# AND getDate<=#2019-02-18#");
```

But this not:

```
private final static String GET_ALL = 
    "SELECT * FROM Notification WHERE postDate>=? AND getDate<=?";

public ArrayList<Notification> getAllNotification(LocalDate postDate, LocalDate getDate) {

    PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(GET_ALL);       
    prepStmt.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(postDate));
    prepStmt.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(getDate));

    ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
}
```

What I'm doing wrong or what I'm not doing. 
I am using of course the ucanaccess library in version 4.0.3. Any suggestion or tip?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Are you getting an error message or are you just getting results that are different from what you expect?

Comment: `java.sql.Date` is poorly designed and long outdated. I don’t remember from which version UCanAccess supports `LocalDate` and the other types from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You should obviously prefer to use `LocalDate´ if U Can. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access for dates '#' is used as an identifier. You will have to explicitly specify the # in the start and end of each date. You can try this and it should work.

```
"SELECT * FROM Notification WHERE postDate>= #?# AND getDate<= #?#";
```

I would use the following syntax for this purpose.

```
private String GET_ALL = "";

public ArrayList<Notification> getAllNotification(LocalDate postDate, LocalDate getDate) {

    GET_ALL = "Select * FROM Notification WHERE postDate >= #" + postDate + "# AND getDate <= #" + getDate + "#";

    PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(GET_ALL);
    ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
}
```

Comment: Also I'm unsure if you can insert arguments into a statement that has been marked as 'final'. Please do check that too.

Comment: unfortunately "UCAExc:::4.0.3 unknown token:"
You can, all other instructions as final work fine.

Comment: Try constructing the query like this inside the method
"SELECT * FROM Notification WHERE postDate>= #" + postDate + "# AND getDate<= #" + getDate + "#";
instead of using the ? wildcard.

Comment: Yes this work fine, i try it, but i can try use class PreparedStatement :)

Comment: did you remove the final keyword? Also see the edited answer.

Comment: yes, i try delete final word but this word is no problem. Yes i can use string connection but i try use class PreparedStatement. Why access cant accept this :prepStmt.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(postDate));

Comment: try printing the prepStmt before calling the executeQuery function and see if the SQL is correct and the parameters have been inserted. 
System.out.println(prepStmt);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188598/discussion-between-faisal-and-light).

Comment: "_Also I'm unsure if you can insert arguments into a statement that has been marked as 'final'_". I'm assuming you're referring to the `final` keyword in `private static final String GET_ALL = ...;`. The presence of this `final` is irrelevant to the `PreparedStatement`. All it does is say the `GET_ALL` variable cannot be reassigned. The `PreparedStatement` does not, _and cannot_, reassign the variable because Java is pass-by-value; also, `String` is immutable.